# How to set image dimensions to parentNode as atrribute with javasript?

Tags: javascript

I need to add image dimensions to parentNode as atrribute with javasript. But I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined`, result in html is  `data-size="undefinedxundefined"`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks you
My JS code:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("wp-post-image");

for (i in imgs){
       var x = imgs.naturalWidth; 
       var y = imgs.naturalHeight;       
       var sizevalue = x+'x'+y;

       imgs[i].parentNode.setAttribute("data-size", sizevalue);
}
```

Html:

```
<a class="post-thumbnail" href="http://www.example.cs/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/hob_10458_2500px.jpg" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" itemprop="contentUrl">
<img width="1000" height="750" src="http://www.example.cs/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Job_10458_2500px.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Fotografie parfem" srcset="http://www.kasparstudio.cs/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Job_10458_2500px.jpg 1000w, http://www.kasparstudio.cs/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Job_10458_2500px-300x225.jpg 300w, http://www.kasparstudio.cs/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/hob_10458_2500px-768x576.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" title="hob_10458_2500px" itemprop="thumbnail"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several problems:

- `for in` is not recommended for looping over an array.
- You were trying to get the `naturalWidth`/`naturalHeight` for the array of images, and not for a single image, and it returned undefined.
- You should use the [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) instead of setting a `data-*` attribute.

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("wp-post-image");

for (const img of imgs){
       var x = img.naturalWidth; 
       var y = img.naturalHeight;       
       var sizevalue = x+'x'+y;

       img.parentNode.dataset.size = sizevalue;
}

console.log(document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("data-size"))
```

```html
<a id="link" href="//stackoverflow.com/"><img class="wp-post-image" src="//stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico"></a>
```

As you can see, the `data-size` attribute of the hyperlink has the expected value.